# ShareLinkTask Serialization.InvalidDataContractException WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm having an issue with the ShareLinkTask function from WP8.
I have an app with different pages (to view Comics - one to navigate through the Comics and one page to list a thumbnailpreview of all Comics).

The ShareLinkTask function works just fine as long as I stay in the MainPage.xaml. But when I switch to the Thumbnails.xaml (via NavigationService.Navigate...), select a new cartoon and share it the ShareLinkTask.Show() will show the sharing page and then crash the whole app.

If I make a try-catch around the ShareLinkTask.Show() no exception is thrown.

Here is the ShareLink function - it's called via the "Hold gesture":

```
        ShareLinkTask shareLink = new ShareLinkTask();

        shareLink.Title = "a";
        shareLink.LinkUri = new Uri(b);
        shareLink.Message = "Look at that handsome cartoon!";

        try
        {
            shareLink.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
        }
```

From the console I get this error line: "System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException" occoured in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll

Now Google doesn't now anything about this problem somehow - to be honest I don't really get / understand what's happening - I don't think that I serialize anything anywhere...

I suggest that I do something wrong by switching back to the MainPage.xaml. All indices etc. are correct and every other function of the app is just working fine.

Does anyone know where to look for the error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I bet the crash doesn't occur on the ShareLinkTask. My money on a non-serializable object put in the phone state or in the application settings.

Comment: This seems legit. But how does it come that this non-serializable object ist created AFTER I visit the other xaml page. I got a longlistselector in that other xmal page - could this be a non serializable object? I thought every created object gets destroyed if I navigate away from the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you call Show, your application is put into a dormant state and may be terminated if the user navigates away instead of completing the task.

When your app is put into a dormant state your data gets serialized, but only classes with "DataContact" attributes can be serialized correctly. So the problem is - **you are holding some UNSERIALIZABLE data in you app** (Like in PhoneApplicationService.Current.State)  . Find out what class causes exception.
Your exception should be like this:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type '**TYPE HERE**' cannot be serialized.

That will give you a hint of what's going on.

Comment: Would it be enough to set this class to null after using it?
And I don't get a specific exception - it just crashes and Ends in the "Debug.Break" without any more Information. Any ways to retrieve more?

Comment: I got it! I had a class that contained Information about the thumbnails and I created a list with this class. As a first step to the solution I created a DataContract that Ignores the Members in the class and it works just fine! How do I solve this more "clean"?
Thanks!

Comment: DataContracts are pretty easy to use. There's plenty of docs covering that topic. 
[For example, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811.aspx).
You just mark your class as `[DataContract]` and fields with `[DataMember]` attributes.
If you got fields of non-primitive types, but another class, you should mark that class as `[DataContract]` too